# Read image from Google Cloud storage and send it using Google Cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to do the following:
Create a Google Cloud Function (http triggered) that simply read an image file from a bucket (Google Cloud Storage) and send it as a response.

I've tried some combinations and I think that it should be something like that:

```
'use strict';
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

exports.sendImage = function sendImage(req, res) {
    let bucket = gcs.bucket('my-bucket-name');
    let myImage = bucket.file('my-image-file.jpg');


    res.contentType('image/jpeg');
    res.end(myImage, 'binary');
};
```

The function above deploys successfully but when I trigger it just using the url (on browser) it shows no results.

I'm doing that as simple as possible because if it works with one image, I can improve the code to call any image.

My final goal is to have something similar to that showed on this post:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556

But running on Google Cloud Functions. If I manage to send a simple image, I can use some module such as [node-image-resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-image-resize) to the final result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well I could find it by myself and I think it can help a lot other people. So do the following:

1 - Create a bucket on Google Cloud Storage, let's say the name is [my-bucket]

2 - Create a Google Cloud Function, let's name it imageServer.

3 - Don't forget to edit the package.json file. My one was as follows:

```
{
  "name": "image-server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

4 - The code to send a simple image is really simple (after I figured that out):

```
'use strict';

const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

exports.imageServer = function imageSender(req, res) {
  let file = gcs.bucket('my-bucket').file('test-1.jpg');
  let readStream = file.createReadStream();

  res.setHeader("content-type", "image/jpeg");
  readStream.pipe(res);

};
```

Obs: The testing image is the file named [test-1.jpg] and it's on bucket's root. So, from here, I was able to send it to the browser. Now it's just a matter of changing the code to achieve my primary goal as I told on my question.

I hope it helps.

Reference links:
[Google Cloud Storage NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage)
[Google cloud Functions Hello World tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, it was super helpful and got me on the right track. I wanted to get a file from a bucket using a Firebase cloud function, which is tightly integrated with Google Cloud Storage, and then serve it over https.

I also wanted to first check if the file in the bucket existed and if not, serve a placeholder image I have in the bucket.

After some googling [which brought me to the file.exists()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/5.1.1/File.html#exists-examples) method examples I ended up with this:

First

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getStorage} = require("firebase-admin/storage");
```

Then

```
initializeApp({
  storageBucket: "my-bucket-name",
});
```

Then I exported a returnPhoto function to serve the photo via https

```
exports.returnPhoto = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let file = bucket.file("image_name.jpg");
  file.exists().then(function(data) {
    const exists = data[0];
    if (exists) {
      file.createReadStream()
          .on("error", function() {
            console.log("Error while fetching the requested photo.");
            res.end();
          })
          .pipe(res.setHeader("content-type", "image/jpeg"));
    } else {
      file = bucket.file("notfound_image.jpg");
      file.createReadStream()
          .on("error", function() {
            console.log("Error while fetching notfound_image.jpg");
            res.end();
          })
          .pipe(res.setHeader("content-type", "image/jpeg"));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing c# application but your reply helped me a lot.

If somebody is interested in c# version here it is

```
namespace ProductivityTools.Journal.ImageProvider
{
    public class Function : IHttpFunction
    {
        const string ProjectId = "ptjournal-b53b0";
        public async Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var client = StorageClient.Create();
            var bucketName = "ptjournaltest1";

            context.Response.ContentType= "image/jpeg";
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                client.DownloadObject(bucketName, "Untitled.png", stream);
                await context.Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```